How to find the total payment based on specific age ranges
I am trying to solve a problem in MySQL where there is an insurance table, through which I need to find the total payment based on age ranges. Such as, 0-10 would have a certain amount of payment, 11-20 a certain amount and so on.
I have written the following code to generate the age range
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN age < 11 THEN '0-10'
        WHEN age > 10 AND age< 21 THEN '11-20'
        WHEN age > 20 AND age< 31 THEN '21-30'
        WHEN age > 30 AND age< 41 THEN '31-40'
        WHEN age > 40 AND age< 51 THEN '41-50'
        WHEN age > 50 AND age< 61 THEN '51-60'
    END AS age_range
    FROM insurance
) age_table
GROUP BY age_range
ORDER BY age_range;

What I want to do now is to grab the payment and sum it according to the age ranges. I can't figure that out

to grab the payment and sum These are a data of different grouping level. You may use GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP, of course - if the output is final data to be displayed, and it won't be processed.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. We don't know what kind of result you want.

You need a conditional sum:
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN age < 11 THEN amount END) AS "0-10",
  SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN amount END) AS "11-20",
  SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN amount END) AS "21-30",
  SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN amount END) AS "31-40",
  SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN amount END) AS "41-50",
  SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN amount END) AS "51-60"
FROM insurance;

See this fiddle with some sample data.
Note: If it's possible you won't get any values for a specific range, the sum will be NULL for those ranges. If this is not intended and you would rather like to get 0 in this case, you can use COALESCE...
...COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN amount END),0) AS "31-40"...
... or add ELSE 0:
...SUM(CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS "41-50"...
The mentioned fiddle shows that, too.
Sidenote: Of course, you can also keep your original > x and < y conditions instead of using BETWEEN. I changed that because I think BETWEEN has a better readability.

When there is no rows which matches some particular condition then SUM will return NULL which may be not safe. I'd prefer to add ELSE 0... https://dbfiddle.uk/2MvKmWxK
